# Update all slide master's and layout's footers

Tags: vba, header, powerpoint, footer

Trying to create a macro to quickly enter in project names to ppt footers. I can only get the top level slide master to accept the input title. I've tried looping through the other slide master layouts with the new footer info but I keep getting errors at the line to write text to the footer in the For loop

```
    Sub footchange()

    Dim myValue As Variant
    Dim sld As Slide

    myValue = InputBox("Enter Presentation Name")

    Set mySlidesHF = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.HeadersFooters

    'Add name to slide master footer
    With mySlidesHF
        .Footer.Visible = True
        .Footer.Text = myValue + "    |   Confidential © 2020"
        .SlideNumber.Visible = True  
    End With

    'Add name to slide master layouts footers
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
       With sld.HeadersFooters
            .Footer.Visible = True 
            .Footer.Text = myValue + "    |   Confidential © 2020"
            .SlideNumber.Visible = True
        End With
    Next
```

Comment: What error do you get and at which line?

Comment: HeaderFooter (unknown member) : Invalid request

at line 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to update all the master slides/layouts by adding a 2nd nested loop for the layouts in each master slide:

```
Sub footchange()

Dim myValue As Variant
Dim sld As Slide

'Add design and layout variables
Dim oMaster As Design
Dim cLay As CustomLayout

myValue = InputBox("Enter Presentation Name")

'Just to show you how many Masters you have
Debug.Print ActivePresentation.Designs.Count

'Loop through them
For Each oMaster In ActivePresentation.Designs

'Use actual Design
Set mySlidesHF = oMaster.SlideMaster
Set myLayoutsHF = oMaster.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts


'Add name to slide master footer
With mySlidesHF.HeadersFooters
    .Footer.Visible = True
    .Footer.Text = myValue + "    |   Confidential © 2020"
    .SlideNumber.Visible = True
End With

'Add name to layouts
For Each cLay In myLayoutsHF
    With cLay.HeadersFooters
        .Footer.Visible = True
        .Footer.Text = myValue + "    |   Confidential © 2020"
        .SlideNumber.Visible = True
    End With
Next cLay

Next oMaster


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the other masters through the DESIGN property:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.design

This code should get you started. Please give feedback if you have troubles.
*(indentations kept against reviewers for better understanding)*:

```
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim sld As Slide

'Insert a Design Variable
Dim oMaster As Design

myValue = InputBox("Enter Presentation Name")

'Just to show you how many Masters you have
Debug.Print ActivePresentation.Designs.Count

'Loop through them
For Each oMaster In ActivePresentation.Designs

'Use actual Design
Set mySlidesHF = oMaster.SlideMaster.HeadersFooters

'Add name to slide master footer
With mySlidesHF
    .Footer.Visible = True
    .Footer.Text = myValue + "    |   Confidential © 2020"
    .SlideNumber.Visible = True
End With

'Another approach would be to change the footer on each slide manually
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
   With sld.HeadersFooters
        .Footer.Visible = True
        .Footer.Text = myValue + "    |   Confidential © 2020"
        .SlideNumber.Visible = True
    End With
Next

Next 'oMaster
```

Comment: I'm still running into the same issue with this update. The addition of the design property is still yielding the same result. The first master changes but there's an error trying to update the additional master layouts

Comment: What error? You have to be more specific or we can not help you at all

Comment: HeaderFooter (unknown member) : Invalid request at line 24

Comment: The code example was supposed to **get you started**. Did you use Debugging? What is the content of the line with the error? 
[Here is a video] (https://www.screencast.com/t/SqjSQZEe) showing you what the code does and how it would point you to the right direction.
Maybe you want to upload your file to a cloud so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for diving into this and uploading the video. The error I was receiving was on the ' .Footer.Text = myValue + "    |   Confidential © 2020" ' line, I believe because applying the .footer property to the wrong higher level property

I can get the top master slides to update but it's the nested ones that are giving me trouble. Here's an image that illustrates the issue I'm running into:

[imgur.com/a/VogZK60](http://imgur.com/a/VogZK60)

Comment: You need to address the Custom Layouts - but I saw you did it already.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to edit the Layout footers by accessing the forms "CaseCode" and "Copyright" of the respective custom layout via:

```
Dim objPowerPoint As New PowerPoint.Application
 
objPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(8) _
    .Shapes("CaseCode").TextFrame.TextRange.text = "Test"
```

I used this as a workaround since the solutions above did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Working on a VSTO project and I encountered the same error as above:

> HeaderFooter (unknown member) : Invalid request at line 24

This code caused it:

```
var footer = pres.HeaderFooters.Footer;
footer.Text = "some text";
```

The solution was simple (but really a hidden bug IMO). You must first set the Footer to Visible:

```
footer.Visible = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
footer.Text = "some text";
```

Hope that helps someone else.